# Difference between @TypeChecked and @CompileStatic

Tags: groovy

Can someone explain the difference between @TypeChecked and @CompileStatic?

I read that with @TypeChecked it is not possible to add new methods at runtime. 
What other features are not allowed?

Which Groovy Features are allowed with @CompileStatic? 
Is the bytecode same as compiled with javac in compare to groovyc and @CompileStatic?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The major difference is the MOP (Meta Object Protocol): `@TypeChecked` keep methods going through the MOP, while `@CompileStatic` generate method calls similar to Java's bytecode. This means their semantic are different, but it also means you can still apply metaprogramming on top of a `@TypeChecked` code, as long as the method call can be resolved at compile time.

The following code shows the MOP acting on a `@TypeChecked` code, and not on `@CompileStatic` code:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic as CS
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked as TC

class Foo {
  def bar = "bar"
}

class TestTC {
  Foo foo

  TestTC() {
    foo = new Foo()
    foo.metaClass.getBar = { "metaClass'd bar" }
  }

  @TC
  def typed() {
    foo.bar
  }

  @CS 
  def compiled() {
    foo.bar
  }
}

assert new TestTC().typed() == "metaClass'd bar"
assert new TestTC().compiled() == "bar"
```

For `@CompileStatic`, yes, Groovy tries to generate bytecode close to what `javac` would output, thus, [their performance are very close](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-20-performance-compared), with a few exceptions.

---

**(Updated 2016-01-13)**

Both `@CompileStatic` and `@TypeChecked` will allow:

- Closures (including Closure delegations through `@DelegatesTo`);
- ASTs (which can be used for [compile-time metaprogramming](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_compile_time_metaprogramming));
- Groovy's syntatic sugar, like those on regex, lists, maps, operator overload and the likes;
- [Extensions](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules).

For `@TypeChecked`, you can also instruct the compiler to ignore some type checks through a [Type Checking Extensions](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Type+checking+extensions), allowing more flexibility. `@CompileStatic` also support this, but is a [little more restrictive](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/type-checking-extensions.html#_type_checking_extensions_and_compilestatic).

Comment: Which one would you use for implementing a DSL? Let's say that it'd be optimal to identify an error in a user's DSL script as **early** as possible.

Comment: @KevinMeredith `@TypeChecked`. It allows the MOP stuff. It will make the DSL engine more verbose to code (i.e., you can't return maps on methods, having to return objects with well defined methods), but it'd identify problems earlier. Note this prohibits some really cool stuff, like [`propertyMissing()`](http://victorsavkin.com/post/3254409403/series-dsls-in-groovy-part-2).

Comment: Have you used `javax.script.*` with `@TypeChecked` before? I'm not sure if that annotation can be used with [ScriptEngine#eval](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String))?

Comment: @KevinMeredith, no idea, I have very little experience with `javax.script` ;-(

Comment: "On @CompileStatic you won't get any metaprogramming besides Extensions" - That is not correct.  Even under `@CompileStatic` you can still take advantage compile time metaprogramming.  `@CompileStatic` doesn't allow most runtime metaprogramming but it does allow other types of metaprogramming (like AST transformations).

Comment: "For @TypeChecked, you can also instruct the compiler to ignore some type checks through a Type Checking Extensions, allowing more flexibility." - You can do the same thing for `@CompileStatic`.  The `extensions` attribute at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/1212b292c34804e3f14af2fbda5daaa85037a039/src/main/groovy/transform/CompileStatic.java#L56 is how those extensions can be expressed.  We do that in Grails, which is how `@GrailsCompileStatic` works.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, the AST part for both annotations is in my answer, but it is not very clear. Updated, thx :-).

Answer (score 10):

tl/dr;

- **@TypeChecked** just checks types during compiling, but compiled code behaves same as without `@TypeChecked`
- **@CompileStatic** checks similar to `@TypeChecked`, but also modifies the code to be type-safe at runtime, meaning methods using dynamic programming will break.