# Does groovy @CompileStatic imply @TypeChecked?

Tags: groovy

I have been adding both `@TypeChecked` and `@CompileStatic` to groovy code.

The compiler accepts this, but is it redundant? Does TypeChecked add anything that CompileStatic does not? The docs seems to imply that CompileStatic is a superset, but stop short of saying so outright. I would like to compile statically while occasionally disabling strict type checking, to let groovy auto-typecast while still catching misspelled references or missing methods.

An example:

```
@TypeChecked
@CompileStatic
class MyClass {
    void simple() {
        // compiles fine statically
    }

    @TypeChecked(SKIP)
    void complicated() {
        // would require too many ugly typecasts
    }

    @CompileDynamic
    void evenworse() {
        // need time to untangle this
    }
}
```

I read [Difference between @TypeChecked and @CompileStatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030026/difference-between-typechecked-and-compilestatic) and it did not answer this specific question. It suggested that TypeCast allows some additional checks, but I don't know if it does additional checks by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes, `CompileStatic` implies `TypeChecked`. Looking into the groovy source for the annotation interfaces `TypeChecked` and `CompileStatic`, we see:

```
// TypeChecked.java
@GroovyASTTransformationClass("org.codehaus.groovy.transform.StaticTypesTransformation")
public @interface TypeChecked {
```

and

```
// CompileStatic.java
@GroovyASTTransformationClass("org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompileTransformation")
public @interface CompileStatic {
...
```

which tells us that the classes doing the actual AST transformations (the work of the annotations) are `StaticCompileTransformation` and `StaticTypesTransformation`.

Looking at the code for those we get:

```
// Transformation for TypeChecked
public class StaticTypesTransformation implements ASTTransformation, CompilationUnitAware {
```

and

```
// Transformation for CompileStatic
public class StaticCompileTransformation extends StaticTypesTransformation {
```

i.e. the transformation for `CompileStatic` extends the transformation for `TypeChecked`, thus it would seem that the behavior of CompileStatic is indeed a superset of the behavior of TypeChecked.

<< edit >>

Digging even deeper, we see that the transformation classes use a visitor pattern and that they have respectively the following methods:

```
    // StaticTypesTransformation, transformation for TypeChecked
    protected StaticTypeCheckingVisitor newVisitor(SourceUnit unit, ClassNode node) {
        return new StaticTypeCheckingVisitor(unit, node);
    }
```

and

```
    // StaticCompileTransformation, transformation for CompileStatic 
    protected StaticTypeCheckingVisitor newVisitor(final SourceUnit unit, final ClassNode node) {
        return new StaticCompilationVisitor(unit, node);
    }
```

which return a custom visitor class for each of the cases.

Looking at the `StaticCompilationVisitor` we see:

```
public class StaticCompilationVisitor extends StaticTypeCheckingVisitor {
    ...
    public void visitClass(final ClassNode node) {
        ...
        super.visitClass(node);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

in other words, the visitor class for `CompileStatic` extends the visitor class for `TypeChecked` and in addition, the `visitClass` method (which does the actual work) in the `CompileStatic` visitor calls `super.visitClass(node)` where `super` is the visitor class for `TypeChecked`.

I think this more or less proves it. The behavior of `CompileStatic` is in fact a superset of the behavior of `TypeChecked`.

Comment: Very thorough, thanks! I have never looked at the Groovy source code, this is interesting.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you feel that this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Good nice analysis of what is happening behind-the-scenes.