# Groovy @CompileStatic and @TypeChecked order, bug or misunderstanding

Tags: gradle, groovy, compiler-errors, annotations

I started getting a strange failure when compiling a gradle task class. This is the task I created:

```
package sample

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency
import org.gradle.api.provider.Property
import org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Input
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Internal
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip
import sample.internal.DataSourceXmlConfig

@TypeChecked
@CompileStatic
class DataSource extends Zip {
    @Internal
    final Property<File> warFile = project.objects.property(File.class)

    DataSource() {
        warFile.convention(project.provider {
            def files = project.configurations.getByName('warApp').fileCollection { Dependency d ->
                d.name == (archiveFileName.getOrElse("") - (~/\.[^.]+$/))
            }
            files.empty ? null : files.first()
        })
    }

    /**
     * This function is used to specify the location of data-sources.xml
     * and injects it into the archive
     * @param dsConf The configuration object used to specify the location of the
     * file as well as any extra variables which should be injected into the file
     */
    @Input
    void dataSourceXml(@DelegatesTo(DataSourceXmlConfig) Closure dsConf) {
        filesToUpdate {
            DataSourceXmlConfig ds = new DataSourceXmlConfig()

            dsConf.delegate = ds
            dsConf.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
            dsConf.call()

            exclude('**/WEB-INF/classes/data-sources.xml')
            from(ds.source) {
                if (ds.expansions) {
                    expand(ds.expansions)
                }
                into('WEB-INF/classes/')
                rename { 'data-sources.xml' }
            }
        }
    }

    private def filesToUpdate(@DelegatesTo(AbstractCopyTask) Closure action) {
        action.delegate = this
        action.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        if (warFile.isPresent()) {
            from(project.zipTree(warFile)) {
                action.call()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When groovy compiles this class, I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileGroovy'.
>
> > BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit '/tmp/bus-server/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/sample/DataSource.groovy'
> >     At line 28 column 28   On receiver: archiveFileName.getOrElse() with
> >     message: minus and arguments: .[^.]+$   This method should not have
> >     been called. Please try to create a simple example reproducing   this
> >     error and file a bug report at
> >     https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY

**Gradle version: 5.6**

**Groovy version: localGroovy() = 2.5.4**

---

### tl;dr, is this a bug or am I missing something about how these annotations work?

The first thing I tried to do was to remove either one of `@TypeChecked` and `@CompileStatic` annotations to see if the error goes away.

**This actually fixed the problem right away**. Compiling the source with either annotations added was successful, but fails when both are present.

I read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717879/does-groovy-compilestatic-imply-typechecked) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030026/difference-between-typechecked-and-compilestatic) and answers regarding the use of both annotations, but none of them seemed to suggest that one cannot use both at the same time.

Finally, I tried switching the order of the annotations to see if that helps and to my surprise, it worked! No compilation errors!

#### This works:

```
@CompileStatic
@TypeChecked
class DataSource extends Zip { ... }
```

---

At this point, I guess **my question** would be, is this a bug or is there something I am not understanding about the use of both of these annotations? I'm leaning more towards it being a bug just because of the fact that the order made the error message go away.

Comment: My guess is, that both annotations are not meant to be used together at all. `@CompileStatic` implies `@TypeChecked`'s behaviour already?

Comment: After more experimentation, I've come to the conclusion not to use both annotations at the same time. More specifically, `@CompileStatic` should be used judiciously and only when you are absolutely sure you are not using any of Groovy's dynamic features.